# Bash: Insert escapes to variable containing spaces

Tags: bash, escaping, spaces

Trying to copy a remote file to my local system using scp in bash
I've obtained the filename that i want and assigned to variable, `$lastModifiedFile`, 
but the problem is it contains spaces in the filename.
To use this variable with scp the spaces need to be escaped with backslashes.
Is there an easy way to format this variable and insert the correct escape character where necessary i.e on spaces?

```
#!/bin/bash

lastModifiedFile=$(sshpass -p 'passw0rd' ssh user@server 'ls -tr /path/output*| tail -n 1')
echo "$lastModifiedFile"

sshpass -p 'passw0rd' scp user@server:"$lastModifiedFile" /root/
```

This is the script output ..

```
[user@host ~]# ./script.sh 
/path/outputSat Mar 09 151905 GMT 2013.html
scp: /path/outputSat: No such file or directory
scp: Mar: No such file or directory
scp: 09: No such file or directory
scp: 151905: No such file or directory
scp: GMT: No such file or directory
scp: 2013.html: No such file or directory
```

I'm looking for something like below, or even a simpler solution? ..

```
escapedFilename=""

for letter in $lastModifiedFile
    if $letter == " "
        $escapedFilename += "\ "
    else
        $escapedFilename += $letter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of leaning toothpick syndrome:

`param=user@server:${lastModifiedFile// /\\ /}`

`sshpass -p 'passw0rd' scp "$param" /root/`

**EDIT:** It seems `scp` does not like me. I needed an additional level of variable in testing ... :)

**EDIT 2:** According to OP's feedback the *exact* solution appears to consist of using `${lastModifiedFile// /\\ \\}` 
I just hope there are no other characters than space that need escaping in some other filenames :)

Comment: The toothpicks seem to be giving incorrect output `scp: /path/outputSat /Mar /09 /151905 /GMT /2013.html: No such file or directory` .. These should be backslashes placed before the space

Comment: Weird. `A="/tmp/foo bar baz";  B=10.0.1.119:${A// /\\ }; scp "$B"  /test` worked for me. May depend on shell used?

Comment: using Bash .. this is what worked in the end, `${lastModifiedFile// /\\ \\}` .. thanks for your help! want to update you answer and ill accept?

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around the filename passed to the remote system so that it is not subject to word splitting.

```
lastModifiedFile=$(sshpass -p 'passw0rd' ssh user@server 'ls -tr /path/output*| tail -n 1')
echo "$lastModifiedFile"

sshpass -p 'passw0rd' scp user@server:"'$lastModifiedFile'" /root/
```

or

```
sshpass -p 'passw0rd' scp "user@server:'$lastModifiedFile'" /root/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
sshpass -p 'passw0rd' scp 'user@server:$lastModifiedFile' /root/
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even typing in the console I need `'server:foo\ bar'` and neither `server:foo\ bar` nor `'server:foo bar'` are enough.

Comment: This gave me `scp /path/outputSun Mar 03 072433 GMT 2013.html` which is not escaped, will not work even manually

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of methods that should handle almost anything (not just spaces) in the filename. First, bash's `printf` builtin has a `%q` format that adds quotes/escapes/whatever to the string:

```
sshpass -p 'passw0rd' scp user@server:"$(printf %q "$lastModifiedFile")" /root/
```

Note, however, that this quotes/escapes/etc it *suitably for interpretation by bash*. If the remote computer's default shell is something else, this may not work in all cases.

Option two is simpler in principle (but a bit messy in practice), and should be compatible with more remote shells. Here, I enclose the filename in single-quotes, which should work for anything other than single-quotes within the filename. For those, I substitute `'\''` (which ends the single-quoted string, adds an escaped single-quote, then restarts the single-quoted string):

```
repl="'\''" # Have to store this in a variable to work around a bash parsing oddity
sshpass -p 'passw0rd' scp user@server:"'${lastModifiedFile//\'/$repl}'" /root/
```